# Prolog trying to use cut or "!"

Tags: prolog

I need to define `segment(X,Y)`, having `X` as a contiguous series of elements in `Y`, and I must use cut in my solution.

How should I use cut? If I use `!`, then I won't get `true` after the first header. This is what I have:

```
segment([],_).
segment([H|T],[H|Y]) :- segment(T,Y).
segment([H|T],[X|Y]) :- segment([H|T],Y).
```

This is my output

```
34 ?- segment(X,[1,2,3,4]).
X = [] 
Action? ;
X = [1] ;
X = [1, 2] ;
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
X = [1, 2, 4] ;
X = [1, 3] ;
X = [1, 3, 4] ;
X = [1, 4] ;
X = [2] ;
X = [2, 3] ;
X = [2, 3, 4] ;
X = [2, 4] ;
X = [3] ;
X = [3, 4] ;
X = [4] ;
```

Comment: Your output contains non-contiguous segments, so you might start looking there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `segment` predicate enumerates the *sub-sequences* of the original list, including "holes" in them.

To produce only contiguous segments of the list, conceptually there are two stages - first we skip along the list, then we collect some of it elements. So we must have two separate predicates for that:

```
segment([],[]).
segment(X,[_|L]):- segment(...).        % we either skip,
segment(X,L):- seg_get(X,L).            % or get some elements

seg_get([A|B],[A|D]):- seg_get(...).    % we get some elements
seg_get([A],[A|_]).                     % or we stop whenever we feel like it
```

I don't see a way to have it all packaged into just one predicate with the same arguments by adding a cut somewhere. That is because the choice in `seg_get` must be only between its two current possibilities, and if we just rename it to `segment`, it will be able to backtrack to other possibilities above it.

Answer (score -1):

In some cases you have to use cut to get your results but there is possibility to do this without it. Here is my solution with a cut, hope it helps.

```
segment([],_). 
segment([H|T],[H|Y]) :- segmenthelperino(T,Y), !.
segment([H|T],[_|Y]) :- segment([H|T],Y).
// This is the helper function
segmenthelperino([],_). 
segmenthelperino([H|T],[H|Y]) :- segmenthelperino(T,Y).
```

cheers..